# Error Resolving Thymeleaf Templates Files when run a jar file in Spring Boot App but runs fine locally

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, thymeleaf, amazon-rds

I have developed one Full Stack `Spring Boot` application using `thymeleaf` and it works fine locally without any issues.

Now I am trying to deploy it to `AWS cloud` but it gave me error [ internal server error ]
I inspected Relational database and tried connecting from app and it works fine.

The only problem it seems to have is it's **unable to resolve templates when a jar file is created** and no templates are getting rendered.

When I launch app, it sends HttpRequest to '/' which renders home template like so and it fails :

```
  // displays home page
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Home Page - Information Keeper");
        return "home"; // return home.html page from templates folder
    }
```

I have all the templates under resources/template/home [ and so on]

My `properties file` is

```
server.port = 5000
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://RDS_Endpoint:5432/myinfokeeper
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

And my pom.xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
 4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>info.keeper</groupId>
<artifactId>info_keeper</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Info_Keeper</name>
<description>Information Keeper using Spring boot, JPA and Thymeleaf with Spring Security.</description>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!--        use postgres sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>InfoKeeperWebApp</finalName>
</build>
```

What should I exactly do ? Why it is not able to resolve those templates with jar but works perfectly on localhost ?

I have looked and tried many solutions on stackoverflow, many of them seem to have problem on localhost but mine is working perfectly on **localhost** but **not on jar** leading to error in **AWS beanstalk** as well.
I have been stuck for days :)

Any help would be appreciated.

And My home.html looks like this :

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:replace="base::layout(~{::div})">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Information Keeper || Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="home d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
       <section>
           <h3>Keep Your Information Secure on Web</h3>
           <h4>Recall Anywhere Anytime</h4>
           <a class="btn btn-warning btn-lg text-white" href="/register">Get Started</a>
       </section>
    <script>
        let items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
        <!-- alert(items.length);  -->
        <!--    remove active class first    -->
        for(i in items) {
       <!-- alert(items[i].className)-->
            if(items[i].className === 'item active') {
                 items[i].classList.remove('active');
            }
        }
        const homeLink = document.getElementById("home-link");
        homeLink.classList.add("active");
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/ this line later and same error I got.

Comment: I don't what exactly because it was working on localhost and not when I deployed. Leading / was causing the problem in the header template when I included that in other pages. Still I have to say it was working on localhost.

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Comment: @overheated yes it has been solved. There was no major issue but one "/" was causing problem from rendering my view even though app was working fine in local computer. If you're having same issue as mine, try removing "/" extra slash from code and it should work.

Comment: I found out to have had a similar problem but it was on multiple points. 
I had all the web files the files in webapp instead of resources and then, after moving the html in /resources/templates and the css,js... in /resources/static/(css)* I had to add these lines in application.propperties  spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/static/**
And also add spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/  Then I also had to check what spring security is allowing and what not. Maybe this will be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when using: 
`<div th:insert="~{/footer.html}"></div>`  
So I changed the code to: 
`<div th:insert="~{footer.html}"></div>` 
It works fine now.

Comment: this change worked perfectly fine for me, thanks! the starting '/' works ok under intellij but from spring boot jar file it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with these configs and make sure your HTML file is containing in the "*templates*" folder, not "*template*" folder in your question

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true 
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
```

Comment: I have all of my html files under templates directory and adding your code in properties file gave no result. I think there is something else to configure for jar file, it works perfectly in localhost when run via without jar.

Comment: I have also included html file, let me know if it has some error.